# Swift Touches not recognized in static table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a table view with static cells.

My second section has a header but no rows, under that section I have a label that when pressed should call sendEmail() function which will open the email app on their device.

I've tried using a label, text view, button, overriding the didSelectCellForRow function and all have failed.

I'm completely lost what ouches aren't being recognized.

I've added print statements to my touchesBegan function but they never print.

What could be the issue?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class InfoTVC: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{

let ownerEmail = "test@email.com"
@IBOutlet weak var contactLbl: UILabel!

// MARK: - View functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


// MARK: - IBOutlet methods

@IBAction func backBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: - Email methods

// Open users email app on device
func sendEmail(){
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients([ownerEmail])
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>Hello I had the chance to use your app and </p>", isHTML: true)
        present(mail ,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        // Failure
        print("failed to open mail")
    }
}

func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
        if contactLbl.frame.contains(location) {
            print("yes")
            sendEmail()
        }
        else{
            print("no")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add tap gesture recognizer instead of handing touches

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.youLabelTapped(_:)))
yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

**OR** alternatively: add target directly to your label

```
yourLabel.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.youLabelTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and you func that will be called:

```
func youLabelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("label tapped")
}
```

**EDIT:**

**REQUIRED:** don't forget to set user interaction enabled:

```
yourLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Not working. I know it should, but for some reason no taps are registered in my view.

Comment: I'm in a navigation controller -> root view -> Show segue to another navigation controller (this is where I am trying to perform the clicks)

Comment: @mocode9 yeah sorry i forgot to mention that as well :) good thing your figured that out!